# How to create textView or webview with Markdown links?

Tags: android

I have a text, which looks like something like this `Test link [linkTest ](https://steamcommunity.com/games/362890/announcements/detail/1716372156964734244)`. And I want to show it in webView or textView like `Test link linkTest`, where linkTest will be clickable (not necessary). How I must parse it? I tried HtmlCompat, but its, obviously, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val textView = TextView(context)
textView.text = "This is sample text. https://google.com"
textView.autoLinkMask = Linkify.WEB_URLS
textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this solve your problem? Give this attribute to your text view in xml file android:autoLink="web"